# Scheme function that receives a function F and a number n

Tags: recursion, scheme

I'm trying to write a scheme function that will return (F,$F^2$,...,$F^n$) where $F^k$ is the composition of F k times

Comment: please show us the code you've written so far, pointing the specific lines where you're having problems. Also add a sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is have a name for the function. Like `compose-n-times`

So with that in mind you would write

```
(define (compose-n-times f n)
  ...)
```

And you would have

- `(compose-n-times f 0)` give the identity function `(lambda (x) x)`
- `(compose-n-times f 1)` would just give back `f`
- You can use recursion to define `(compose-n-times f n)` in terms of `(compose-n-times f (- n 1))` and the "compose" function.

Define the compose helper function like this

```
(define (compose f g)
  (lambda (x) ...))
```

Feel free to ask if anything here is unclear or you need more help.